# Quosure with in a nested function

Tags: r, dplyr, quosure

I am struggling to write a function **fun2** that uses **fun1**... and keep getting errors. I have written a simplified example below. It is the first time I deal with "tidy evaluation" and not sure to understand the in and outs of it.

**Example dataframes:**

```
d1 = data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  EXPR = c(2, 8, 3, 5, 7, 20, 1, 5, 4)
)

d2 = data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
  NUM = c(22, 50, 31)
)
```

**First function**

```
fun1 <- function(
  df1 = "df 1", 
  df2 = "df 2",
  t1 = "threshold 1",
  expr_col = "expr column", 
  id_col = "sample column - must be present in df1 and df2") {

  # dataframes
  df <- df1
  db <- df2

  # quosure
  enquo_id <- enquo(id_col)
  enquo_expr <- enquo(expr_col)

  # classify
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(threshold = t1) %>% 
    mutate(class = ifelse(!!enquo_expr > t1, "positive", "negative")) %>% 
    mutate(class = factor(class, levels = c("positive", "negative")))

  # calculate sample data
  df.sum <- df %>% 
    group_by(!!enquo_id, class) %>% 
    summarise(count = n()) %>% 
    complete(class, fill = list(count = 0)) %>% 
    mutate(total = sum(count), freq = count/total)

  # merge dataframes
  df.sum <- left_join(df.sum, db, by = quo_name(enquo_id))

  # return
  return(df.sum)
}
```

If I run a test of this, I get a dataframe in return, as expected

```
test <- fun1(df1 = d1, df2 = d2, t1 = 3, expr_col = EXPR, id_col = ID)
```

**Second funtion**
Now with **fun2**, I am trying to use fun1 in a for loop to iterate from ti to tf of the seq vector:

```
fun2 <- function(
  df1 = "df 1", 
  df2 = "df 2",
  expr_col = "expr column", 
  id_col = "sample column - must be present in df1 and df2",
  ti = "initial value",
  tf = "final value",
  res = "resolution") {

  # define variables for fun1
  var1 <- enquo(d1)
  var2 <- enquo(d2)
  var3 <- enquo(t1)
  var4 <- enquo(EXPR)
  var5 <- enquo(ID)

  # get sequence of values
  seq <- seq(from = ti, to = tf, by = res)

  # open list
  t.list <- list()

  # Loop ----
  for (i in seq_along(seq)){
    t1 <- seq[i]
    t.list[[i]] <- fun1(df1 = var1,
                        df2 = var2,
                        t1 = var3,
                        expr_col = var4,
                        id_col = var5)
  }
  df.out <- plyr::ldply(t.list, rbind)

  ### Return ---
  return(df.out)
}
```

But if I run this

```
test <- fun2(df1 = d1, df2 = d2, expr_col = EXPR, id_col = ID, ti = 1, tf = 10, res = 1)
```

I get an error message

```
Error in (function (x)  : object 'EXPR' not found
```

I tried various things... and I am kind of stuck here. I guess I am not using **enquo()** properly. I can get it to work by not using **varX** and putting directly the actual appropriate name of each element in the **fun1** arguments, but the whole point of doing this, to me, is to make it "*generalisable*" and therefore specify the arguments only in **fun2** which will then be passed to **fun1**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Passing `EXPR` and expecting it to work implies `EXPR` can be found in the global environment (and it's not, judging by the code you provided). Perhaps you meant to refer to a dataframe column called `EXPR`? Or maybe you meant to `attach()` a dataframe?

Comment: `EXPR` here is the column name of the dataframe `d1`... but indeed, my code doesn't seem to do the trick...

Comment: When you pass `EXPR` to `fun2()`, you pass it as an object `EXPR`, not a dataframe column. Could it be that you meant `d1$EXPR`?

Comment: You didn't use your argument names in `fun2()`.  For example, your argument name is `expr_col` but you use `EXPR`. Same problem for `id_col` vs `ID`.  I think you want, e.g., `var4 <- enquo(expr_col)`.  You would need to unquote all variable names for use in your function within `fun2()` (`expr_col = !! var4)`.  Your datasets and constants (arguments `df1`, `df2`, and `ti`) can likely be used directly, like `fun1(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, t1 =  ti, expr_col =  !! var4, id_col = !! var5)` (although I'm a little confused by your use of `t1` vs `ti` in your for loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for your answer aosmith. I am now sorted using the following code:

```
fun2 <- function(
  df1 = "df 1", 
  df2 = "df 2",
  expr_col = "expr column", 
  id_col = "sample column - must be present in df1 and df2",
  ti = "initial value",
  tf = "final value",
  res = "resolution") {

  # define variables for fun1
  var4 <- enquo(expr_col)
  var5 <- enquo(id_col)

  # get sequence of values
  seq <- seq(from = ti, to = tf, by = res)

  # open list
  t.list <- list()

  ### Loop --------------------------------------------------------------
  for (i in seq_along(seq)){
    t1 <- seq[i]
    t.list[[i]] <- fun1(df1 = df1,
                        df2 = df2,
                        t1 = t1,
                        expr_col = !!var4,
                        id_col = !!var5)
  }
  df.out <- plyr::ldply(t.list, rbind)

  ### Return ---
  return(df.out)
}

# TEST FUN2
test <- fun2(df1 = d1, df2 = d2, expr_col = EXPR, id_col = ID, ti = 1, tf = 10, res = 1)
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is going to work you are actually unquoting without a qusiquotation context here, e.g., you are unquoting outside a dplyr environment, as in `f1`.